# Method to recognize the age of a firebug from the pattern on its back

Tags: entomology, development

Can I recognize the age of a firebug from the pattern on its back?

If yes, what pattern shows what age/stage?

Below is what I extrapolated from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug), but is there a more precise scale with more steps? (I could not find more than this with google).

Nymph:[image] Adults:[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is more or less yes. Normally Firebugs (*Pyrrhocoris apterus*) go through 5 nymph instar stages (as do most [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera)), where they resemble the adults more and more as they grow. Only adults are winged and have have functional reproductive organs. This type of metamorphosis is called [*hemimetabolous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemimetabolous) or simple metamorphosis (in contrast to [Holometabolism or complete metamorphosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holometabolous)). However, I cannot find a good overview of the instar stages of Firebugs to link to.

A generic overview of Heteroptera (True Bugs) can bee seen here 
(from [www.amnh.org/learn/biodiversity_counts](http://www.amnh.org/learn/biodiversity_counts/ident_help/Parts_Arthropods/metamorphosis.htm)):

[image: development of Heteroptera (True Bugs)]

This picture shows (at least) three instars + adults of Pyrrhocoris apterus (from http://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/17248017). The large nymph with 3 dots along the midline is the final 5th instar nymph:

[image: Pyrrhocoris apterus instars + adults]

However, due to hormonal disruptions there have been cases with even more nymph stages (6th and 7th instars with adult characteristics), but this is under unnatural laboratory conditions (e.g. [Slama & Williams 1965](http://www.pnas.org/content/54/2/411.full.pdf) and [Konopova et al. 2011](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0028728)). Konopova et al (2011) also has pictures of instar stages 4 & 5 (along with gene knowdown versions).

Comment: Nice referenced info. The first image would be even better if indicated the patterns too :-)

Comment: I'm sure you can find one for Firebugs in a suitable book. However, the graph I posted is a general overview of Heteroptera, which consists of >40000 species, and the growth patterns naturally differs quite alot within the taxon.